# Adding 'selected' attribute to user's selected option after 'change' with jQuery

Tags: jquery, attributes, html-select

I have a select element that I am adding options to dynamically using data from a variable called 'results':

HTML:

```
<select id="categories">
    <option selected disabled>Select your category</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
$.each(results.Subcategories, function(index,category) {
    var category = '<option value="'+category.Name+'" data-index="'+index+'">'+category.Name+'</option>';
    $('#categories').append(category);
});
```

This works correctly and I am able to choose between the dynamically added options in the select element.

What I need to do now is get the 'value' attribute of the currently selected AFTER the user has chosen it from the added options. This is where I am getting stuck. I thought that something like this would work:

```
$('#categories').on('change', function() {
    var optionSelected = $("#categories option:selected", this);
    console.log($(optionSelected).data("value"))
});
```

But the selected attribute does not move on the options when I choose a new one, so I am unable to target that attribute to get the value.

Assuming the approach above is solid, how do I get my newly selected option to have the selected attribute so I can target it and get the value? Or is there a better approach that I'm missing? Thanks in advance.

Comment: just do $(this).val() or this.value to get the selected value.

Comment: @DinoMyte - but how do I know what 'this' is for the newly selected option, without the 'selected' attribute?

Comment: 'selected' attribute specifies which option should be pre-selected in the select element when it is loaded. are you trying to insert the option from external event and have it displayed selected in the select element ?

Comment: I see, I think I misunderstood the selected attribute. All I really need to get is the value of the currently selected option after any change.

Comment: In that case, 
just do $(this).val() or this.value to get the current selected value.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was misunderstanding the use of the selected attr. Your solution is correct.

Comment: In case this helps anyone - to get the value of a custom data-attr on the currently selected option I used: $('select').find(':selected').data('myAttr'));

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Selected attribute will select an option from load. What you need is this.val() or you could use plain javascript and use getElementById(id of your option element).value() and get the value that way.

Comment: Thanks, yes I was misunderstanding the use of the selected attr. Your solution is correct.

Comment: It's this.value, not this.val()

Comment: You can use both. In jQuery it is $(this).val() and when using pure JavaScript you can use .value() His question tags jQuery. I just gave him the option of using either.